# Extremely loud noise on ASUS E200HA

Tags: sound, asus, battery

My ASUS E200HA keeps emitting a high-pitched, extremely loud noise. Sometimes this happens immediately after I pull out the charging cable, in which case the beep only persists for a few seconds. Sometimes it happens when the Laptop is just on idle, in which case the beep usually persists for longer until I force it to restart.

It happens on both Ubuntu 20.04.6 and 22.04.3. The beeping also occurs if the laptop sound is muted. So far I haven't found a reliable way to recreate the issue every time.

I suspect, it has something to do with power/battery. My charging port is slightly bent from having been dropped once but charging still works. Perhabs the beep is a warning that the charger is damaged? If so, how do I turn it off? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A laptop with a damaged charging port that makes noises sounds like a fire hazard. You might want to take it to a repair shop to get it checked out. Just suppressing the sound might not be the best approach.